# ESB WSO2 | Trying to send an email through email connector and getting "org.wso2.carbon.connector.email.send cannot be found" error

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager, esb, connector

I'm trying to send an email using email connector from esb wso2 but I'm getting this error:

```
Invoking Target EIP Sequence org.wso2.carbon.connector.email.send paramNames : [from, to, subject, content, contentType]
[2022-07-22 10:52:14,113] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator} - Sequence template org.wso2.carbon.connector.email.send cannot be found
[2022-07-22 10:52:14,121] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.debug.SynapseDebugManager} - Mediation flow terminated for id urn:uuid:3f3f9864-bbc1-4e95-a4bf-1574196dfb8c
[2022-07-22 10:52:14,121]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver} - Executing fault handler due to exception encountered
[2022-07-22 10:52:14,121]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} - ERROR_CODE : 0
[2022-07-22 10:52:14,121]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} - ERROR_MESSAGE : Sequence template org.wso2.carbon.connector.email.send cannot be found
[2022-07-22 10:52:14,122]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.FaultHandler} - ERROR_DETAIL : org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Sequence template org.wso2.carbon.connector.email.send cannot be found
```

This is my api which I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/api/send/email" name="api.send.email" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <property expression="json-eval($.from)" name="from" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="json-eval($.to)" name="to" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="json-eval($.subject)" name="subject" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="json-eval($.content)" name="content" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="json-eval($.contentType)" name="contentType" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <log level="custom">
                <property expression="$ctx:from" name="Log_from:"/>
                <property expression="$ctx:to" name="Log_to:"/>
                <property expression="$ctx:subject" name="Log_subject:"/>
                <property expression="$ctx:content" name="Log_content:"/>
                <property expression="$ctx:contentType" name="Log_contentType:"/>
            </log>
            <email.send configKey="TEST_SMTP_CONNECTION">
                <from>{json-eval($.from)}</from>
                <to>{json-eval($.to)}</to>
                <subject>{json-eval($.subject)}</subject>
                <content>{json-eval($.content)}</content>
                <contentType>{json-eval($.contentType)}</contentType>
            </email.send>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

I think the problem is based on the fact that I don't think I added the connector on my project in the correct way.
So, first of all I added a connector on my main project (where I have APIs, endpoints etc) - **Right Click - Add or Remove Connector/Module - then I added the email connector**)
Then I created a new Connector Exporter on my project (**Right Click on an empty space on my Project Explorer - I named the exporter 'test' - and I think here is the problem:**
[image]

**What Group ID, Parent Group ID and Parent Artifact ID I should choose?** (same question when I'm making Composite Application for connector)

LATER EDIT*:
When I'm deploying de car. app for the email connector I'm getting these errors:

```
Error in instantiating class : org.wso2.carbon.connector.operations.list.EmailGetAttachment java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wso2/carbon/connector/core/exception/ContentBuilderException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
```

```
Unable to update status for :  {org.wso2.carbon.connector}email :: Template configuration : null cannot be builtfor Synapse Library artifact : getEmailAttachment org.apache.synapse.deployers.SynapseArtifactDeploymentException: Template configuration : null cannot be builtfor Synapse Library artifact : getEmailAttachment
```

Comment: Also when I'm trying to select something from that Dropdown "Specify Parent from Workspace" it's all empty spaces

Comment: Hi,

Request you to generate App Password for Gmail by following https://devanswers.co/create-application-specific-password-gmail/ and use that 16 digit generrated password inside your localentry(TEST_SMTP_CONNECTION) rather than original password of gmail account

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions, if you have a Maven MultiModule Project you can get the details of the parent project from the `pom.xml` of the parent project.(This is the root pom.xml typically)

The easiest way to resolve your problem is to create your project from an existing template which will make sure projects are created correctly. Inorder to do that, follow the steps below.

1. Open Integration Studio and Go to Help -> Getting Started.

[image]

2. Then select the `Email Service` sample project, give it a name and create the project.

[image]

3. Now you should have a full working project with a Connector Exported.

[image]

In the future for creating new projects, you can refer to [this](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/develop/create-integration-project/) document.

Comment: Thanks. But what if I already have an project without a Maven MultiModule Project?

Comment: I just edited my original post, if you can look again ^^