# Sending Email in WSO2 EI using Email connector V1.0.2 - ERROR: InvokeMediator Sequence template org.wso2.carbon.connector.email.send cannot be found

Tags: email, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am trying to send Email by using [WSO2 Email connector V1.0.2](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/connectors/email-connector/email-connector-example/) in WSO2 EI 6.5.0.

Receiving `ERROR` like below in log

```
InvokeMediator Sequence template org.wso2.carbon.connector.email.send cannot be found
```

WIRE Logs:

```
    [2023-01-06 14:15:24,412] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "POST /email/send HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,428] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,428] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.30.0[\r][\n]"
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,428] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Accept: */*[\r][\n]"
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,428] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Cache-Control: no-cache[\r][\n]"
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,428] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Postman-Token: caf3e8c5-a4df-4ad2-9ee0-fb96c36a3225[\r][\n]"
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,428] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Host: localhost:8280[\r][\n]"
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,428] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br[\r][\n]"
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,428] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,428] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "Content-Length: 435[\r][\n]"
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,428] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "[\r][\n]"
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,428] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "{[\r][\n]"
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,428] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "    "from": "mail2justinraj96@gmail.com",[\r][\n]"
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,428] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "    "to": "mail2justinraj96@gmail.com",[\r][\n]"
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,428] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "    "subject": "This is the subject",[\r][\n]"
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,428] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "    "content": "This is the body",[\r][\n]"
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,428] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "    "contentType": "text/plain",[\r][\n]"
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,428] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "    "attachments": [[\r][\n]"
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,428] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "        {[\r][\n]"
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,428] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "            "name": "sampleimagefile.png",[\r][\n]"
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,428] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "            "content": "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="[\r][\n]"
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,428] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "        }[\r][\n]"
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,428] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "    ][\r][\n]"
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,428] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 >> "}"
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,428] []  INFO - LogMediator EmailService**** = Called***, Log_from: = mail2justinraj96@gmail.com, Log_to: = mail2justinraj96@gmail.com, Log_subject: = This is the subject, Log_content: = This is the body, Log_contentType: = text/plain
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,428] [] ERROR - InvokeMediator Sequence template org.wso2.carbon.connector.email.send cannot be found
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,428] [] ERROR - EmailService Sequence template org.wso2.carbon.connector.email.send cannot be found
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,441] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted[\r][\n]"
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,441] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "Date: Fri, 06 Jan 2023 08:45:24 GMT[\r][\n]"
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,441] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,444] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,444] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "[\r][\n]"
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,444] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "0[\r][\n]"
[2023-01-06 14:15:24,444] [] DEBUG - wire HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-4 << "[\r][\n]"
```

API Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/email" name="EmailService" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST" uri-template="/send">
        <inSequence>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="EmailService****" value="Called***"/>
                <property expression="json-eval($.from)" name="Log_from:"/>
                <property expression="json-eval($.to)" name="Log_to:"/>
                <property expression="json-eval($.subject)" name="Log_subject:"/>
                <property expression="json-eval($.content)" name="Log_content:"/>
                <property expression="json-eval($.contentType)" name="Log_contentType:"/>
            </log>
            <email.send configKey="smtpsconnection">
                <from>{json-eval($.from)}</from>
                <to>{json-eval($.to)}</to>
                <subject>{json-eval($.subject)}</subject>
                <content>{json-eval($.content)}</content>
                <contentType>{json-eval($.contentType)}</contentType>
            </email.send>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

LocalEnrty:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<localEntry key="smtpsconnection" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <email.init>
        <connectionType>SMTPS</connectionType>
        <port>465</port>
        <host>smtp.gmail.com</host>
        <username>mail2justinraj96@gmail.com</username>
        <password>mypassword</password>
        <name>smtpsconnection</name>
    </email.init>
</localEntry>
```

Note:

- In above `<password>` field i tried to give both gmail password and [App Password](https://devanswers.co/create-application-specific-password-gmail/), none of them are working.
- Project is imported from `Getting started page` of `WSO2 Integration Studio 8.0.0`

I followed below prerequisites suggested by [WSO2 Doc](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/connectors/email-connector/email-connector-example/)

- Go to the security tab in your account settings and turn on less secure app access.--> this option not supported by google, so i tried [App Password](https://devanswers.co/create-application-specific-password-gmail/)
- Go to the gmail settings -> Forwarding and POP/IMAP and enable IMAP under IMAP access.
- Email Connector enabled in WSO2 EI 6.5.0 Server

API Hit:

[image: Postman]

Email Connector in WSO2 EI Console:

[image: Email connector]

[Reference link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73077118/esb-wso2-trying-to-send-an-email-through-email-connector-and-getting-org-wso2)

[Reference Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73243035/wso2-email-connector-issue-with-sending-attachments)

How can we resolve this?

Comment: Have you deployed the connector to the EI runtime?

Comment: Hi @ycr,
As i have mentioned above (in prerequisites ), email connector already enabled in WSO2 EI managemnt console (added screenshot now)

Comment: Is this happening in a clustered environment?

Comment: Hi @ycr,
It is running in a standalone server(running in my local system)

Answer (score 0):

1. can you try with outlook smtp? Please check with outlook and see if
   you are able to receive emails via email connector.  `Server Address: smtp-mail.outlook.com Username: Your Outlook Email Address (e.g. example@outlook.com) Password: Your Outlook Password Port Number: 587 (With TLS = true)` You can try Gmail connector as
   well
   https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Using+the+Gmail+Connector
2. I also noticed that you are sending attachments in postman while its not handled in your API

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/email" name="EmailService" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST" uri-template="/send">
        <inSequence>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="EmailService****" value="Called***"/>
                <property expression="json-eval($.from)" name="Log_from:"/>
                <property expression="json-eval($.to)" name="Log_to:"/>
                <property expression="json-eval($.subject)" name="Log_subject:"/>
                <property expression="json-eval($.content)" name="Log_content:"/>
                <property expression="json-eval($.contentType)" name="Log_contentType:"/>
            </log>
            <email.send configKey="smtpsconnection">
                <from>{json-eval($.from)}</from>
                <to>{json-eval($.to)}</to>
                <subject>{json-eval($.subject)}</subject>
                <content>{json-eval($.content)}</content>
                <contentType>{json-eval($.contentType)}</contentType>
                <attachments>{json-eval($.attachments)}</attachments>
            </email.send>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Comment: Hi @Ayub Jamal,
Even after removing attachment from input request, the same result or adding attachment in email.send operation the same result. by using email connector need to achieve this, any issue with email connector?